# Pool function causing errors with imputed data when using r-mice

Tags: r, deprecated, lm, imputation, r-mice

New to R, so apologies for any misunderstandings in advance.

I'm trying to carry out some linear regressions with imputed data. I've carried out the linear regressions with complete cases, but want to compare imputed models.

I'm using mice, and have created my imputed data:

```
imp_data2 <- mice(data,m=5,maxit=20,meth='pmm',seed=12345)
```

Then:

```
# Stack imputed datasets in long format, exclude the original data
impdat <- complete(imp_data2,action="long",include = FALSE)
```

I've then specified the model:

```
model1 <-with(data = impdat, exp = lm(nat11 ~ sex + AGE + (fasbathroom+fasbedroom+fascomputers+
                            fasdishwash+fasfamcar+fasholidays)))
```

But when I try to use the pool() function to give a model summary:

```
summary(pool(model1))
```

I get some bizarre error codes, and I've not found anything that can help at all. I can use summary(model1), and it works fine, but I cant get a summary of the pooled model. Any advice?

The errors I get are:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class qr
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In get.dfcom(object, dfcom) : Infinite sample size assumed.
2: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated") 
3: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated") 
4: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated") 
5: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")
6: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated") 
7: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")
```

*EDIT*

If it helps, I used the traceback() function. The output was:

```
12: stop("No tidy method for objects of class ", class(x)[1], call. = FALSE)
11: tidy.default(X[[i]], ...)
10: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
9: lapply(fitlist, tidy, effects = "fixed", parametric = TRUE, ...)
8: eval(lhs, parent, parent)
7: eval(lhs, parent, parent)
6: lapply(fitlist, tidy, effects = "fixed", parametric = TRUE, ...) %>% 
bind_rows()
5: summary.mira(fitlist, type = "tidy", exponentiate = FALSE)`
4: summary(fitlist, type = "tidy", exponentiate = FALSE)
3: pool.fitlist(getfit(object), dfcom = dfcom)      
2: pool(model1)
1: summary(pool(model1))
```

---

If I enter

```
str(complete(imp_data2,action=1))
```

The output is as follows:

```
 'data.frame':   5286 obs. of  45 variables:
  `$ AGE             : num  11.6 12 12.3 11.2 12 ...`
  `$ sex             : num  1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...`
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "female" "male"
$ grade           : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:3] "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Country specific grade (15 year old)" "Country specific grade (13 year old)" "Country specific grade (11 year old)"
$ fasfamcar       : num  3 3 3 2 3 3 3 2 3 3 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:3] "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Yes, two or more" "Yes, one" "No"
$ fasbedroom      : num  1 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Yes" "No"
$ fascomputers    : num  4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "More than two" "Two" "One" "None"
$ fasbathroom     : num  4 4 3 4 3 4 4 3 4 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "More than two" "Two" "One" "None"
$ fasdishwash     : num  2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Yes" "No"
$ fasholidays     : num  4 4 3 3 1 4 4 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "More than twice" "Twice" "Once" "Not at all"
$ health          : num  1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "Poor" "Fair" "Good" "Excellent"
$ lifesat         : num  9 8 9 7 8 10 10 10 8 9 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:11] "10" "9" "8" "7" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:11] "10 Best possible life" "9" "8" "7" ...
$ feellow         : num  5 5 4 4 5 5 5 5 4 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Rarely or never" "About every month" "About every week" "More than once a week" ...
$ irritable       : num  5 5 4 4 3 3 5 5 5 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Rarely or never" "About every month" "About every week" "More than once a week" ...
$ nervous         : num  4 1 4 3 4 3 5 4 4 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Rarely or never" "About every month" "About every week" "More than once a week" ...
$ sleepdifficulty : num  5 5 1 4 5 5 5 5 4 4 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Rarely or never" "About every month" "About every week" "More than once a week" ...
$ fmeal           : num  1 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 4 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Never" "Less often" "About once a week" "Most days" ...
$ smok30d_2       : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "30 days (or more)" "20-29 days" "10-19 days" "6-9 days" ...
$ drunk30d        : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Yes, more than 10 times" "Yes, 4-10 times" "Yes, 2-3 times" "Yes, once" ...
$ likeschool      : num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "I don't like it at all" "I don't like it very much" "I like it a bit" "I like it a lot"
$ schoolpressure  : num  2 1 4 1 1 3 1 2 3 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:4] "4" "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:4] "A lot" "Some" "A little" "Not at all"
$ studtogether    : num  2 2 3 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ studhelpful     : num  1 2 3 1 1 2 2 2 1 3 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ studaccept      : num  2 3 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ teacheraccept   : num  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ teachercare     : num  1 1 3 1 3 1 1 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ teachertrust    : num  1 1 3 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Strongly disagree" "Disagree" "Neither agree nor disagree" "Agree" ...
$ beenbullied     : num  1 3 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Several times a week" "About once a week" "2 or 3 times a month" "It has happened once or twice" ...
$ cbeenbullied    : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Several times a week" "About once a week" "2 or 3 times a month" "It has happened once or twice" ...
$ fight12m        : num  1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "4 times or more" "3 times" "2 times" "1 time" ...
$ friendhelp      : num  7 7 4 5 7 5 2 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ friendcounton   : num  7 6 4 5 7 5 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ friendshare     : num  7 5 3 5 7 5 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ friendtalk      : num  7 4 3 5 6 2 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ hadsex          : num  2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
$ agesex          : num  1 3 5 1 5 4 3 3 4 5 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:6] "6" "5" "4" "3" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "16 years old and older" "15 years old" "14 years old" "13 years old" ...
$ contraceptcondom: num  2 2 1 3 1 2 1 1 1 3 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:3] "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Don't know" "No" "Yes"
$ contraceptpill  : num  3 3 3 3 3 3 2 3 2 3 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:3] "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Don't know" "No" "Yes"
$ motherhome1     : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
$ fatherhome1     : num  2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "No" "Yes"
$ talkfather      : num  1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Don't have or see this person" "Very difficult" "Difficult" "Easy" ...
$ talkmother      : num  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Don't have or see this person" "Very difficult" "Difficult" "Easy" ...
$ famhelp         : num  7 7 5 6 7 7 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ famsup          : num  7 7 5 6 7 7 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ famtalk         : num  7 7 6 6 7 6 1 7 7 7 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:7] "7" "6" "5" "4" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:7] "Very strongly agree" "6" "5" "4" ...
$ nat11           : num  2 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Always" "Often" "Sometimes" "Hardly ever" ...
- attr(*, "variable.labels")= Named chr(0) 
..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0) 
- attr(*, "codepage")= int 65001
```

Comment: Maybe one or several variables in your imputed dataset are of a format/class that `mice::pool` cannot handle? Could you show us the output of `str(complete(imp_data2,action=1))` ?

Comment: Thanks so much for offering to help!
Output says:



'data.frame': 5286 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ AGE             : num  11.6 12 12.3 11.2 12 ...
 $ sex             : num  1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "female" "male"
 $ grade           : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:3] "3" "2" "1"
.. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "Country specific grade (15 year old)" "Country specific grade (13 year old)" "Country specific grade (11 year old)"
 $ fasfamcar

Comment: There's a lot of output (more than I can fit into a comment, but that's the jist....

Comment: Based on the error message, I assumed that you have a variable that has a class `qt`, i.e. `attr(, "class") = chr [1:?] "qt"`. I wondered what type it is (numeric, character, logical) and how it could be transformed (or just the class attribute removed) to avoid the error.

Comment: @benimwolfspelz
The only line that looks different to the rest is at the end:
    `$ nat11           : num  2 2 3 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:5] "5" "4" "3" "2" ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Always" "Often" "Sometimes" "Hardly ever" ...
 - attr(*, "variable.labels")= Named chr(0) 
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr(0)
attr(*, "codepage")= int 65001`

The rest are similar to:

    `$ sex             : num  1 1 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "value.labels")= Named chr [1:2] "2" "1"
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "female" "male" `

Comment: if you the full output to the question it will be easier to help

Comment: Hi @AbdessabourMtk, I wasn't able to fit it into the character limit in the comments, I'll add this to the main post, thanks for your help.